# I am getting Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'classifiedsCtrl' is not registered

Tags: angularjs

New to angular. Had it running fine with no controller then added a ng-controller directive to HTML markup and broke interpolation. Using Angular 1.6. What am I missing?

```
<head>
     <script src ="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"> </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller = "mainCtrl">
        <p>Hello JS</p>
        <p ng-if = "true">GM</p>
    </div>


    <script>
        var module = angular.module("myapp" , []);
        module.controller("mainCtrl", Main);

        function Main(){

            console.log("controller");
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: you are missing `ng-app="myapp"` in `body`

Comment: Thank you. Silly mistake..:)